# Do I need S/N for new motherboard

Tags: motherboard, dell-latitude, serial-number

I am planning to buy new motherboard since my currenct motherboard is broken. 
In some site I see that motherboard is sorted by S/N (serial number) 
Since I  dont know where to find S/N of motherboard, but I suppose I need to disassemble it. 
Do I really need this S/N new motherboard or it's not important ? 
This part confusing me, someone tell me that I need someone that it's not important
What do you think guys ?

**Btw** My model of laptop is `Dell Latitude E5530`

Comment: Is your laptop under warranty?

Comment: Sure,it's under warranty

Comment: Go to the dell support site and put in your service tag. This is found on the bottom of the laptop on a sticker. Dell will usually replace the motherboard for you.

Comment: As I see it's usually like LA-9702P and soo on. 
Do I need to disassemble it to find service tag or ... ?

Comment: @Robby - you need the service tag.

Comment: @Robby, the service tag is on a sticker. It will look something like [this](https://www.dell.com/support/contents/uk/en/ukbsdt1/article/product-support/self-support-knowledgebase/locate-service-tag/Notebook)

Comment: Thank you :) I am gona find it :)